# Trimming a color bar after normalize in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, boxplot, colorbar

I have aligned a color bar to the x-axis of a horizontal box plot.

As you can see in the figure at the bottom, there is a blank area along the x-axis.

So I want to trim the x-axis together with the color bar, which was normalized by `vmin` and `vmax`

Any idea how to accomplish that?

Thanks a lot!

```
test_data = [np.random.normal(mean, 1, 10) for mean in range(400, 500, 10)]

### set sns style
sns.set_style('white')

### set fig, ax
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,2))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.10,0.10,1.2,2])

### Define color bar
# choose color map
cmap = plt.get_cmap('nipy_spectral')
# normalize min and max
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=380,vmax=780)
# assign cmap and norm
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])

### Plot color bar (change "pad" to adjust distance of color bar to x-axis)
plt.colorbar(sm, ticks=np.linspace(380,780,11), location="bottom", pad=0)

### Plot boxplot
bplot = ax1.boxplot(test_data, vert=False, patch_artist=True)

### Set axis
ax1.set_yticklabels(["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"])
ax1.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax1.set_xlim(380,780)   

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You are setting `fig.add_axes([0.10,0.10,1.2,2])` which is quite a lot outside the available 0,1 region for x and y. Why?

Comment: What does the four number means exactly? I noticed you have written x0, y0, width, height in the code below, I don't understand the meaning of x0 and y0 in particular. Thanks!

Comment: x0,y0 is the lower left point.  Everything is measured in [figure coordinates](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) which go from 0,0 at the lower left of the surrounding plot to 1,1 at the top right.

Comment: Thanks again Johan! You are very helpful. Have a great day and 2021!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to place the colorbar exactly aligned with the main ax, is to also create its ax as `cax = fig.add_axes([...])` using the same x and width as the main ax and adapting the y and height. Then the colorbar can be created as `plt.colorbar(sm, ticks=np.linspace(380, 780, 11), orientation='horizontal', cax=cax)`.

As you want to reduce part of the colorbar, it might be easier to draw it via `imshow()` using an extent to align it with the x-axis.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl

test_data = [np.random.normal(mean, 1, 10) for mean in range(400, 500, 10)]

sns.set_style('white')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 3))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.10, 0.17, 0.88, 0.80])  # x0, y0, width, height in figure coordinates
cax = fig.add_axes([0.10, 0.12, 0.88, 0.05], sharex=ax1)  # use same x0 and width

### Define color bar
cmap = plt.get_cmap('nipy_spectral')
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=380, vmax=780)
xmin, xmax = 380, 500
cax.imshow(np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100).reshape(1, -1), extent=[xmin, xmax, 0, 1], cmap=cmap, norm=norm, aspect='auto')
cax.set_yticks([])

bplot = ax1.boxplot(test_data, vert=False, patch_artist=True)

ax1.set_yticklabels(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"])
ax1.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelbottom=False)
cax.set_xticks(np.arange(xmin, xmax + 1, 20))

plt.show()
```

[image: plot with attached colorbar]

`imshow()` can also be used to color the boxplot rectangles in a similar way. The example below uses adapted example data to better illustrate the concept. Note that `imshow` resets the xlims and ylims, so they need to be saved first and reset afterwards.

```py
test_data = [np.random.uniform(mean - 20, mean + 20, 10) for mean in range(400, 500, 10)]

sns.set_style('white')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 3))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.10, 0.17, 0.88, 0.80])  # x0, y0, width, height in figure coordinates
cax = fig.add_axes([0.10, 0.12, 0.88, 0.05], sharex=ax1)  # use same x0 and width

### Define color bar
cmap = plt.get_cmap('nipy_spectral')
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=380, vmax=780)
xmin, xmax = 380, 510
cax.imshow(np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 200).reshape(1, -1), extent=[xmin, xmax, 0, 1], cmap=cmap, norm=norm, aspect='auto')
cax.set_yticks([])

bplot = ax1.boxplot(test_data, vert=False, patch_artist=True, medianprops={'color': 'white'})

ax1.set_yticklabels(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"])
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelbottom=False)
cax.set_xticks(np.arange(xmin, xmax + 1, 20))
ymin, ymax = ax1.get_ylim()

for art in ax1.artists:
    art.set_facecolor('none')  # make transparent
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = art.get_path().get_extents().extents
    ax1.imshow(np.linspace(x0, x1, 100).reshape(1, -1), extent=[x0, x1, y0, y1],
               cmap=cmap, norm=norm, aspect='auto', zorder=0)
ax1.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
ax1.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
```

[image: boxplot with gradient fill]

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot for the explanation though I do not understand fully! But I know how to tune with your script. Thanks again!!!!